# Lavender is white

Tags: plant-health

Why is my normally purple lavender flower, white this year?  Does the soil need to be more acid like hydrangeas?  I have grown lavender for many years and this is the first time the flowers have turned white.

Comment: Is this a change to just one plant or all of them? Are they old plants or recently grown from seed?

Comment: Soil should not be too much acid (better:neutral to slightly acid). What did you change this (or last year) vs. other years? Fertilizer? Or maybe just climate. Do you see other differences? Leaves? Smell?

Comment: A  photo would be helpful - lavender flowers do not  change colour according to soil ph - professional growers keep the soil ph neutral to slightly alkaline, but only because they're growing as a crop, its not actually that fussy about soil ph.